# How to format string to date from array in foreach loop?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following code that works perfect with a pre-formatted DateTime array:

```
foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    while ($range['start'] <= $range['end']) {
        $date = $range['start']->format('Y-m-d');
        $dates[$date] = (isset($dates[$date]) ? $dates[$date] : 0) + 1; 1;//define new $dates array
        $range['start']->modify('+1 day');
    }
}

$sold_out = array_filter($dates, function($n) { return $n >= 7; });

echo implode(',', array_keys($sold_out));
```

But, my production array is not "pre-formatted" as DateTime

In the linked Fiddle you can see we are linking to a native array where the values are 'strings'
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/zni4-enk5

This produces an '**Exception:** Call to a member function format() on string'
on the line where we step through the dates:
$range['start']->modify('+1 day');

To test change the array target from $ranges to $ranges2:
**Example:** foreach ($ranges2 as $range) {

Is the problem not properly being able to set the values as DateTime?

**GOAL:** Output comma delimited dates that share a date that intersects x number of times within the provided date ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `DateTime`'s `createFromFormat()` to convert these values to `DateTime` values.

`DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-02-18');`

```
foreach ($ranges2 as $range) {
    $range['start'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $range['start']);
    $range['end'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $range['end']);
    while ($range['start'] <= $range['end']) {
        $date = $range['start']->format('Y-m-d');
        $dates[$date] = (isset($dates[$date]) ? $dates[$date] : 0) + 1; 1;//define new $dates array
        $range['start']->modify('+1 day');
    }
}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: Remember we are dealing with variables and not able to change the native array where each date is a String ($ranges2 = array(...).